# How can i validate form using jquery,

Tags: jquery

How can i throw an alert when the field is empty, Currently it always throw alert even when the firstname field is not empty. Here is my jquery code:

```
    $("#button1").click(function() {

        if($("#fname").val() == ''){

            alert("Please enter firstname");


            }
    });
```

Comment: Add the OR or AND  operator to your if query. The OR operater in Javascript is `||`and the AND counterpart is `&&`.

Comment: using console.log can help here e.g console.log($("#fname").val()) 
you might have 2 text boxes called fname - could that be the problem.
Can you show your html?

Comment: Another helpful page is https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

We should use `$(document).ready(function(){}` function. The Code inside this function only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute. Try below... Hope This will Help you.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
      $("#button1").click(function() { 
          if($("#fname").val() == ''){ 
              alert("Please enter firstname"); 
          } 
      }); 
}); </script>
```

[Click Here](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) for more details.

Comment: Even when I put the first name in it keeps on throwing the alert.

Answer (score 1):

Hi works for me as per Mohit's solution. One thing I might be tempted to change is to check for the field length instead

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
      $("#button1").click(function(){
        if($("#fname").val().length === 0)
          alert("Please enter firstname"); 
      });
    });
```